# Switch statements and incompatible types?

Tags: java, switch-statement, incompatibletypeerror

I have a method that is supposed to take a string parameter representing a barcode, and return the digit equivalent of that string. Code below:

```
public int codeToDigit (String code) throws IOException
{                   
       switch (code)
       {
          case "||:::": return 0; 
          case ":::||": return 1; 
          case "::|:|": return 2; 
          case "::||:": return 3; 
          case ":|::|": return 4; 
          case ":|:|:": return 5; 
          case ":||::": return 6; 
          case "|:::|": return 7; 
          case "|::|:": return 8; 
          case "|:|::": return 9; 
       }
}
```

I'm confused about two things. First, what should I put as the default? Right now, I have 10 just as a placeholder. But that's not correct. Also, when I compile it, I get the following error:

BarCode.java:56: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: int
       switch (code)

They're incompatible types apparently? Any input as to how to solve this? Thanks for the help!

Edit: Many of you mentioned upgrading to Java 7, which I have done. I'm working off of Java 7 and just updated Update 51. However, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: As a sidenote: you don't have to put all these `break` statements since it will never reach that point anyway, `return` stops it sooner.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish here. The switch statement takes and integer or a character. If your trying to look for a whole string in the switch statement I will have to check it out when I can get eclipse to open. Integers and characters are easy. You could take which ever character you are looking for a just look for that char. But I think for the most part if I was looking for a set of characters (string) I would switch and use if statements.

Comment: Java 1.7+ allow `switch(<String>)`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you cannot `switch` on `String`s in versions of java < SE 7 so you should probably upgrade. If not, convert to if/else.

Secondly, remove all of your `break` statements, as these will throw a compiler error even if you fix that problem.

Finally, you should throw some sort of an error in the default column if there is no legitamate return to give. An `IllegalArgumentException` would probably be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.7+, you get other compiler errors about `break;` being unreachable (they're unnecessary because of your `return` statements), as has been mentioned already.  You can remove them and it'll compile fine.

However, in Java 1.6 and before, you get the incompatible types error.  This is because [`String`s in `case` statements were supported in Java only starting with 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html).

To solve this, upgrade your Java to at least 1.7, or try a numeric value or an enum for your codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, as the other answers have stated:  Upgrade to Java 7.  If for nothing else, do it for the security, and convenience (ironic as it may be that those two things come from the same result).

However, if, for some reason, upgrading your Java version is not an option (which it may not be, if you're using a school's lab machine, or relying on an instructor's compiler to handle it properly), you could also make an enumeration that has strings as data, convert your string to the proper enumeration member with a simple "parse" method, and then switch over the enumeration, instead.

This would probably just replicate your issue, but it's a valid method.

I won't pretend to have cracked open (or spoken to someone who has) the Java 1.7 compiler, but suffice to say that it generates "generally more efficient bytecode from switch statements that use String objects than from chained if-then-else statements" ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)).

However, a switch over an enumeration would also work quite well, though I'm not sure how you'd manage to get the naming to represent your data in the same way as you did, here...